# Cuntz's Original Paper Introducing Cuntz Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103901288) is Cuntz's paper "Simple $C^*$-algebras Generated by Isometries". I'm having trouble understanding section 1.7. First, let me set up some notation:

With $n =2,3,...,\infty$ fixed, given $k \in \Bbb{N}$,

$$W^n_k := \{(j_1,...,j_k) \mid j_i \in \{1,...,n\}\},$$

$W_0^n := \{0\}$, and $W^n_{\infty} := \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} W_{k}^{n}$. Let $S_0 = 1$, and given $\alpha = (j_1,...,j_k) \in W_{k}^{n}$, define the isometry $S_{\alpha}$ as $S_{\alpha} = S_{j_i} S_{j_2} ... S_{j_k}$. It turns that any word in $\{S_i\} \cup \{S_i^*\}$ can be written as $S_{\mu} S_{v}^*$ for unique $\mu,v \in W_{\infty}^{n}$

Let $\mathcal{F}_0^{n} = \Bbb{C}1$, let $\mathcal{F}_{k}^{n}$ be the $C^*$-algebra generated by the set $\{S_{\mu} S_{v}^* \mid \mu, v \in W_{k}^{n} \}$, and let $\mathcal{F}^n$ be the $C^*$-algebra generated by $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_{k}^{n}$.

I think I've given all the notation needed to describe my issue (if not, I can try to clarify or you can look at the linked paper). In section 1.6, Cuntz sets out to describe the algebra $\mathcal{P}$ generated *algebraically* by $\{S_i\} \cup \{S_i^*\}$. Let $V$ denote $S_1$ and $V^{-1}$ denote $S_1^*$. He claims that

> since any $A \in \mathcal{P}$ is a linear combination of words, $A$ can be written in the form
> $$A = \sum_{i=-N}^{-1} V^i A_i + A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i V^i,$$
> where the $A_i \in \mathcal{F}^n$.

I'm having trouble verifying this decomposition holds. First, it doesn't quite make sense to me. The algebra $\mathcal{P}$ is generated *algebraically* from words in those isometries, whereas $\mathcal{F}^n$ is a $C^*$-algebra. Why do we need elements from a big $C^*$-algebra to describe elements in $\mathcal{P}$. I guess if someone could help me prove that $A$ decomposes in that way I would understand, but I don't see how to prove it.

Comment: Note that you are looking at the algebra generated by the $S_i, S_i^*$ separately, whereas on the other hand you are looking at the C* algebra where every $S_\mu$ term must always be taken in product with an equally long $S_\nu^*$ term. You don't need the $A_i$ to be in the C* closure of this second thing, just in the algebra generated by it, but maybe the author felt like he had introduced enough notation already and decided against introducing a new letter for this one-shot use and instead took $A_i\in \mathcal F^n$

Comment: @s.harp Oh, so the $A_i$ come from the algebra generated by $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}_{k}^{n}$, which of course is contained in the $C^*$-algebra generated by the same union. Do you have any idea how to show $A$ can be decomposed as $$A = \sum_{i=-N}^{-1} V^i A_i + A_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{N} A_i V^i?$$

Comment: @s.harp I think I might have figured it out. Give me a few minutes to type it up.

Comment: Write $A= \sum_{i=-N}^N M_i$ where $M_i$ is some word of the form $S_{\mu(i)}S_{\nu(i)}^*$ where $\mu(i) - \nu(i) = i$. Then $M_i = (S_i^*)^n (S_i)^nM_i$, for $i$ negative you have $A_i:=(S_i)^nM_i \in\mathcal F_n$, for $i$ positive write $M_i = M_i (S_i^*)^n (S_i)^n$ and then $A_i := M_i (S_i^*)^n \in \mathcal F_n$. This is the basic idea, which is simple enough. That it works is the content of the proposition 1.7

Comment: @s.harp Possibly a minor point, but $\mu(i)$ and $\nu(i)$ aren't integers, but tuples of natural numbers. Not sure if that changes your proof very much.

Comment: Yes, I should have written $|\mu(i)|-|\nu(i)|$